# Loading a popover view when app opens

Tags: ios, objective-c

Following along with [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/video-recording-playback-ios-programming/), I'm trying to make a very simple iOS video app to learn the api. The tutorial tell us to put a button on the view that, when pressed, uses the UIImagePickerController api (a modal or popup view) to show the camera controls. For my app, I wanted the UIImagePickerController (or rather the camera functionality) to appear, not when the button was pressed, but rather when the app opened. When I moved the code into viewDidLoad, I got this error message

```
2014-06-27 17:04:48.754 VideoBlah[33679:60b] Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x1658d4d0> on <ViewController: 0x165be6f0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

I therefore tried to get `self.view` to `presentViewController` like this

```
[self.view presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

but UIView doesn't have the selector presentViewController.

Is there a way to get the popup view controller for the UIImagePickerController to appear when the app opens rather than waiting for the user to present a button?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
//    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
//        
//        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
//        picker.delegate = self;
//        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
//        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
//        picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
//        
//        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
//    }

}

- (IBAction)captureVideo:(id)sender {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code in viewDidAppear.